# Why does only one of my SBS 2011 IIS Websites connects to the MySQL but the other one does not?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I have multiply websites configured and setup on a SBS 2011 virtual machine.

The default wwwroot website connects to MySQL without any trouble with the host set to 'localhost'. But the second website that has it's own seperate directory location along side the wwwroot directory can not access the MySQL Database with 'localhost' as its host connection.

Anyone have any ideas why the default site connects to the MySQL Database but the second website does not?

Okay here is my directory structure.

inetpub

../websites

../../website1

../wwwroot

```
<?php

$db_username="username"; $db_password="password"; $database="database"; $db_host="localhost";

mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die("cannot connect");  mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select Database");

?>
```

When ever I run this code in the wwwroot directory it works but not when I execute this code in the website1 directory.

**UPDATE!!!**

So it seems that it is not my connection to the MySQL database that is the problem it is the include php function.

So my problem is now why does the php include function work within the wwwroot folder and not the website1 folder?

Thanks

Foo

Comment: normally it should not happen, but could you show us an example of your directories structure ... also how you be sure they don't connect

Comment: It could be pretty much everything, please be more specific.

Comment: Okay here is my directory structure.

inetpub

../websites

../../website1

../wwwroot

> <?php
> 
> $db_username="username"; $db_password="password";
> $database="database"; $db_host="localhost";
> 
> mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or
> die("cannot connect");  mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot
> select Database");
> 
> ?>

When ever I run this code in the wwwroot directory it works but not when I execute this code in the website1 directory.

Comment: Could you tell us what the error message says exactly? Or what exactly happens when you try it on website1?

Comment: I receive the error message when the mysql_connect fails and dies. The message is cannot connect.

But I am now actually getting somewhere myself with this problem and I seem to have managed to get it to connect.

Before I was trying to include the database connection info and the database connection string.

Now it connects but I seem to have found other php problems. I just need to check my code and tweak it to make it work the way I want it to work.

But now I am confusing myself.

Comment: So it seems that it is not my connection to the MySQL database that is the problem it is the include php function.

So my problem is now why does the php include function work within the wwwroot folder and not the website1 folder?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I have solved the problem myself. I have been programming with php for several years now and have just realized that I need to follow and remember all the new changes.

Too many mistakes for me to list but thanks anyway people for reading my problem.

Ensure all PHP code is encased in

```
 <?php ?>
```

and not

```
 <? ?>
```

It might work on one server but it won't work on servers running the latest version of PHP 5.6

Comment: This is slightly incorrect, for a while what you said about "Short tags" is correct. but as of 5.4 short tags are ALWAYS on: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php - I imagine the reasoning for this is because people like to use short tags in templates. Additionally, you need to use "<?= ?>" for short tags - note the equals sign.